# OpenJMS : impossible to set the INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY

Tags: java, initial-context, openjms

I wrote the below code to set my `Context` :

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://localhost:3035");
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.exolab.jms.jndi.InitialContextFactory");
Context context = new InitialContext(properties);
```

However, when I execute the jar, I get this exception (NB : not when I make the compilation + sorry I couldn't write it here) : http://pastebin.com/5i9SbvEh

I don't know why, since I actually have the `jndi`, `jms`  and `openjms` jars (I did it with `One-JAR`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot those dependecies... :

openjms-common  0.7.7-beta-1    openjms-common-0.7.7-beta-1.jar openjms-net 0.7.7-beta-1    openjms-net-0.7.7-beta-1.jar commons-codec  1.3 commons-codec-1.3.jar commons-logging1.0.4 commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
concurrent  1.3.4   concurrent-1.3.4.jar jms    1.1 jms-1.1.jar 
jndi    1.2.1   jndi-1.2.1.jar spice-jndikit    1.2 spice-jndikit-1.2.jar

(http://openjms.sourceforge.net/usersguide/jars.html , PART "Runtime JARS")